# How to make this search query work together with these placeholders and what is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

The first query work when I remove the placeholder `:p` and replace with `?` and at the `$stmt->execute(array(':s' => $s));` replace with `$stmt->execute([$s]);` while the code after `if(!empty($search) {` is not working, look below

```
    $mydb = new Mydb;
    //a possessed id
    $s = 1;
    $q = 'SELECT name, street FROM mydata WHERE possessed_id = :p ';
    $search = $_POST["search"]["value"];
    if(!empty($search) {
        $q .= 'AND (name LIKE :n OR street LIKE :s)';
    }
    $stmt = $mydb -> prepare($q);
    $stmt->bindValue(':n', '%'.$search.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':s', '%'.$search.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    
    $stmt->execute(array(':s' => $s));
```

the goal is to display all data in a table and allow search

Comment: Parameter `:p` is never bound, and `PDO::execute()` (I assume your class extends it) accepts an array which associative keys don't contains the `:`.

Comment: Have a read of this, explains it much better than I ever could: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#like

Comment: @AymDev it give `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`

Comment: @adttmkbttmkb Yes that's what I'm saying, you declared `:p` but you never bind its value, and on the other hand you conditionally define parameters `:n` & `:s` and you always bind their values. It makes no sense.

Comment: @Erik I don't understand your comment, OP put the `%` in the bound value, not in the query.

Comment: @AymDev read the whole thing please, not just the first two sentences.

Comment: @Erik I still don't understand what this paragraph about `LIKE` and parameters have to do with the question, sorry.

Comment: @AymDev, on this keyword LIKE I have to put a placeholder otherwise if I remove then there is a possibility of sql injection to occur, however should I try multiple? I'm still lost

Comment: AH I see, I clicked that. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `$search` is empty, you have the parameter `:p` in your query but you try to bind the `:n` & `:s` parameters.
When `$search` is not empty, you have the 3 parameters (`:p`, `:n` & `:s`) but you still don't bind `:p`.
In any case you have a different number of declared and bound parameters.

You should take care of `:p` and only bind the other parameters when they exist in the query:

```php
$q = 'SELECT name, street FROM mydata WHERE possessed_id = :p ';
$search = $_POST["search"]["value"];

// Default parameters
$parameters = [
    'p' => $s
];

// Add ":n" & ":s"
if('' !== $search) {
    $q .= 'AND (name LIKE :n OR street LIKE :s)';
    $parameters['n'] = '%' . $search . '%';
    $parameters['s'] = '%' . $search . '%';
}

$stmt = $mydb->prepare($q);
// Send the parameters
$stmt->execute($parameters);
```

I assumed a corrected version of your parameters and their value and used only 1 way to bind the parameters to the query with an array during the `execute()` call.

> I also removed the `empty()` call ([here](https://beberlei.de/2021/02/19/when_to_use_empty_in_php_i_say_never.html)'s why).